# TIdeSDK Python module import

Tags: python, tidesdk

Folks... New to TideSDK.  Want to use the tool to develop cross platform scientific applications.  I need to import external modules and package them into the app.  Is this possible?

Comment: What research have you done on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've done this on multiple occasions. What has worked for me is to place the folder with the module into the "Resources" directory of your TideSDK project and use your usual "import" to load the module.