# Python & Tide SDK - import external module?

Tags: python, module, external, tidesdk

Since python is bundled with the Tide SDK, I can't figure out how to use access external modules. I've tried copying the module folder "Lib/site-packages/YourModuleHere" to the tide SDK directory, and this suggestion here: [TIdeSDK Python module import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115173/tidesdk-python-module-import) but with no success. The module I'm trying to use is https://github.com/burnash/gspread

Any ideas?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

to convert your python code to exe with all needed modules then use `Ti.Process.createProcess()` to call your exe

Answer (score 0):

In current version of TideSDK, loading custom python modules is not supported.It loads default set of Python modules compiled within the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck installing a view external modules by running setup.py install from TideSDK's python.exe

This post helped:

[Installing python modules in TideSDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372667/installing-python-modules-in-tidesdk)

For Windows 7:

launch powershell

cd into the module folder

run:

```
C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\Modules\python\1.3.1-beta\python.exe setup.py install
```

It installs the module in \Lib\site-packages, as it should, and I'm able to use the import function in the python code.

This has worked for PIL and I'm trying to get it to function with pywin32. I'd love to hear if it works for other modules